# javascript multiple input textarea validation

Tags: javascript

I have 'n' numbers in a TEXTAREA on a form. After the user enters some value in the TEXTAREA, I need to validate it's not a duplicate of any other value.

Example:

```
TEXTAREA_1 value =
10
20
30
40
10
```

It should alert and say 'value 10 was entered more than once'. Please help me with the JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var nums = textarea.value.split('\n').sort();
var prev;
for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++ ) {
    if (prev && nums[i] == prev) {
        alert('value ' + prev + ' was entered more than once');
        break;
    }
    prev = nums[i];
}
```

Comment: Hai Anatoliy, your answer is right for me, now my script for this scipt has complete. thank you very-very much...

Comment: +1 leveraging sort. However note this is purely string-based, it doesn't do numerical comparison so '0' is a different thing to '00' or '0.0'.

Answer (score 0):

pure DOM/JS solution:

```
  <form id="foo">
    <textarea id="numbers-textfield" cols=40 rows=20>10
    20
    30
    40
    50
    60
    60</textarea>
    <br>
    <input type=submit value=submit>
</form>
<script>
    (function() {
    var form = document.getElementById('foo'),
        textarea = document.getElementById('numbers-textfield'),
        inArray = function( value, arr ) {
        for ( var i = arr.length; i--; ) {
            if ( value == arr[i] ) {
            return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
        }


    form.onsubmit = function() {
        var value = textarea.value.split(/\s+/), len = value.length, stack = [], errors = false;


        for ( var i = 0; i<len; ++i ) {
        var isNum = !isNaN( value[i] );
        if ( !isNum ) { continue; }
        if ( errors ) { break; }
        if ( !inArray( value[i], stack ) ) {
            stack.push( value[i] );
        } else {
            errors = true;
            alert( value[i] + ' already in stack');
        }
        }

        if ( errors ) {
        return false;
        }

    }

    })();
</script>
```

Comment: oh, I just misunderstood the question. Give me a min then.

Comment: hai Meder, thank for your answering, i have the answer from Anatoly. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
  $("form").submit(function() {
    var txt = $("#TEXTAREA_1");
    var vals = txt.val().split("\n");
    var len = vals.length;

    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      for(var j = i + 1; j < len; j++) {
        if(vals[i] === vals[j]) {
          alert("Duplicate values are not allowed");
          txt.select();
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

[It works](http://blog.josh420.com/examples/TextareaMultipleValues/)

Comment: Hai Josh, thank you for your answering, i have the answer from Anatoly. thank you very much...

Comment: You're welcome!  I've actually had to do this before.  This could be easily changed to not use jQuery, too.